# How to sign in second user in incognito window to test actioncable

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I'm trying to sign in a 2nd user to see if ActionCable is working.  I have my app open in a regular Chrome window on localhost:3000 and I also have it open in an incognito window also localhost:3000

From https://github.com/rails/actioncable-examples:

1. Open two browsers with separate cookie spaces (like a regular session and an incognito session).
2. Login as different people in each browser.
   3  Go to the same message.
3. Add comments in either browser and see them appear real-time on the counterpart screen.

However, when I sign in the 2nd user in the incognito window, the 1st user gets logged out.

I'm using ng-token-auth and devise_token_auth for authentication.

Also, I have an ng-click that toggles the navbar to collapse

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" ng-click="isNavCollapsed = !isNavCollapsed">
  <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

When I click the hamburger button in either the regular window or the incognito window, the navbar collapses in both windows.

I thought an incognito window would give me a completely separate cookie jar and therefore separate $scopes but I guess not.

I hope someone can tell me what is going one.

Comment: Can you add sample code as well? The ng-click looks fine

Answer (score 0):

When using Incognito mode, your Sesssion stays active on every tab/window as long as you do not close each and every one of them as stated on the Incognito start page:

> Pages you view in incognito tabs won't stick around in your browser's history, cookie store, or search history after you've closed all of your incognito tabs. Any files you download or bookmarks you create will be kept.

Having stated this, your session is completely different from the one in a normal tab/window, so the action cable test should work.

This may fail if by any means your logic overrides the logged in user when a new user gets logged in.